# getView() Method and Checkbox

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android studio and I'm working on a project. I have a `ListView` and it consists of `CheckBox` and `TextView`. I've added two buttons `add` and `delete`. If I check the `CheckBox` and press the delete button, that item is deleted. Thus, I designed a custom adapter and it has a `getView()` method.

This `getView()` method includes a listener for `CheckBox`. When I check the `CheckBox`, is the `getView()` method called or only listener is executed?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView;
    final int pos = position;

    rowView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);

    TextView textView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.content);
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)rowView.findViewById(R.id.check);

    textView.setText( list.get(pos).getContent() );

    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if( checkBox.isChecked() ){
                list.get(pos).setChecking(1);
            }
            else {
                list.get(pos).setChecking(0);
            }
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: Stuff like this is easily tested with some log statements or the debugger. It would be a lot faster even than writing a whole SO question.

Comment: You've written all the code relevant to your question already. The only thing left is to add `Log.d()` statements and check it for yourself.

Comment: Where does I have to add Log.d() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I check the checkbox, is the getView() method called or only
>   listener is executed ?

Only the code within your listener will be executed. In this case:

```
if( checkBox.isChecked() )
{
   list.get(pos).setChecking(1);
}
else
{
   list.get(pos).setChecking(0);
}
```

Comment: Since this code is located in getView() method, I think that whole getView() is executed. Thank you for giving an answer instead of giving negative vote. Some people are new and they may ask basic questions.

Comment: You're welcome, but you can believe me: Only the code within the listener is executed if you click on a CheckBox!

Answer (score 0):

Adapter's `getView()` is called everytime the view for the list item is either created or reused. This method is executed before the user gets to see the item (for this reason it is recommended to keep this method short and free from heavy computations).

When the checkbox is checked, `getView()` will not be called rather the listener of the checkbox will be called. In this particular case what you are trying to achieve you will have to set a `OnCheckedChangeListener` and `OnClickListener` to checkbox and button respectively.

Your CustomAdapter.java will look something like this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<String> list;
    public  static List<Integer> selectedPositions;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context,List<String> list){
        this.context=context;
        this.list=list;
        this.selectedPositions=new ArrayList<>(0);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list==null?0:list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){

            /****** Inflate rowitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain rowitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder(vi);


            /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vi.setTag( holder );
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

       //Set listeners for checkbox and button

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(compoundButton.isChecked()){
                    selectedPositions.add(position);
                }else{
                    int count=0;
                    for(int item:selectedPositions){
                        if(item==position){
                            selectedPositions.remove(count);

                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        return vi;



    }


    private class ViewHolder{
        CheckBox checkBox;
        TextView textView;
        ViewHolder(View itemView){

            checkBox=(CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            textView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        }
    }
}
```

The Delete Button in the activity will be handeled like this :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(CustomAdapter.selectedPositions != null && 
 !CustomAdapter.selectedPositions.isEmpty()){
                for(int count = 0;
                        count < CustomAdapter.selectedPositions.size(); count++){
                    list.remove(CustomAdapter.selectedPositions.get(count));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
        }
    });
```